# PHP: Convert a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following array:

```
Array
(
  [entity] => Array
    (
      [title] => Array
        (
          [empty] => error message
        )
      [link] => Array
        (
          [empty] => error message
        )
      [authors] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
            (
              [full_name] => Array
                (
                  [max_lengh] => another error message 2
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

How to convert it into a form like:

```
$array = [
'entity[title]' => 'error message',
'entity[link]' => 'error message',
'entity[authors][0][full_name]' => 'another error message 2',
];
```

I think this is done via recursion or use the references but the two things I'm not good)
Thanking you in advance!

Comment: You can do that using `foreach()`

Comment: Maybe try some things, you might surprise yourself, but if you run into problems, you can ask *specific* questions and share the code you've tried, which is more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not properly explained to the task.
Thanks to all.

```
function format(array $array, $withLastKey = false) {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
        $returnArray = [];
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            $keys = [];
            for ($i = $iterator->getDepth(); $i >= 0; $i--) {
                $childKey = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
                // if first element then without bracket
                $keys[] = ($i == 0) ? $childKey : '[' . $childKey . ']';
            }
            $keys = array_reverse($keys);
            ($withLastKey) ?: array_pop($keys);
            $returnArray[implode('', $keys)] = $value;
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are totally mixed up about array syntax. There is no reason you would want an array like that. Only point to make is that the [empty] becomes [0], you might try var_export to show it better.

What is this for?

```
$array = [
'entity[title]' => 'error message',
'entity[link]' => 'error message',
'entity[authors][0][full_name]' => 'another error message 2',
];
```

What even is it...? You have the [] inside the quotes. I mean, you could do very easily

```
$array2['title'] = $array['title'][0];
```

etc.

Another thing to address, why you have it like that in the first place?

Anyway, it should work something like this.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
   if (isset($value[0]) && !is_array($value[0]))
   {
      $array[$key] = $value[0];
   }
}
```